# Remote host Jenkins change permisions

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-build

I am using Jenkins on Azure and when I build the project Jenkins Fetches the Repository, it builds the image:

```
WEB_IMAGE_NAME="${ACR_LOGINSERVER}/front-end-image:kube${BUILD_NUMBER}"
${WORKSPACE} = "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/reply-frontend"
docker build -t $WEB_IMAGE_NAME ${WORKSPACE}
```

from the docker file

```
FROM nginx
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

I get the following error:

```
Step 1/3 : FROM nginx
 ---> ae513a47849c
Step 2/3 : COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder738543803/dist: no such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tried to change the permissions from the remote Jenkins.

```
azureuser@jenkinsvm:~$  ls -ls /var/lib/jenkins/
4 drwxrwxrwx  6 jenkins   jenkins    4096 May 16 12:49 workspace
```

But is Jenkins the one who has the permissions, I want to assign the permissions to my **azureuser**

How I can do that?

Comment: I think it could be because of unavailability of the specified file.

Comment: I have tried changing the permissions, but It doesn´t allow me azureuser@jenkinsvm:~$ chmod 777 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace

chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace': Operation not permitted

Comment: from the above logs, you are not the root user to change the permissions.

Comment: What I am thinking is that the docker needs the permission, is the one who want to copy the image to the jenkins workspace docker build -t $WEB_IMAGE_NAME ${WORKSPACE}